# PXException - not showing email in full

Tags: acumatica

I have a validation that throws a PXException in an action, and the message has an email address. Something strange is occurring where the email is not printed in full in the message.

> For example, it is showing "The following email is already in use:
> myemail" instead of "The following email is already in use:
> myemail@email.com" i.e. it removes the part of the email after the @
> symbol.

I am using this approach to throw the error:

```
throw new PXException(EDMessages.REGISTRATION_EMAIL_ALREADY_INUSE, row.Email);
```

Is this standard Acumatica behavior?
As a workaround, I can try to use Ask rather than PXException, but it would be good to know why this is happening.

Comment: Interesting.   I found that I can reproduce this, but the full email address displays in the trace that accompanies PXException even though the presentation layer seems to cut off the resulting string starting with the @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's strong indication that Acumatica uses that character for routing exception message to a specific HTML frame. Internal format goes like that: '$target=frame_name@message'.

I suspect this JavaScript snippet from Acumatica framework is causing the issue:

```
// extraction of redirect message
var ar = result.split('@', 2), msg = ar.length > 1 ? ar[1] : null;
result = ar[0];
```